# Displaying foreign key with DRF create api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

Display Foreign Keys correctly

I have 2 models in DRF:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Location, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('country', 'city', )
        permissions = (
                ('can_view', 'Can View'),
                ('can_modify', 'Can Modify'),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.country + ":" + self.city)
```

```
class Holiday(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='location_country', on_delete='CASCADE')
    city = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='location_city', on_delete='CASCADE')
    holiday_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Holiday, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.country + ":" + self.city + ":" + self.holiday_date)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('country', 'city', 'holiday_date')
```

When trying to create a Holiday (in browser via api), for country and city field I get dropdown as below:

country: country_name:city_name

city: country_name:city_name

I want to display these fields correctly so that country and city fields are displayed properly.

I understand the current output is because of **str** definition in Location models and I need that to display the table fields in django admin.

How can I overwrite these for the Create API View only (or for all other views that I may create later).

Below is the create API I am using:

```
class HolidayCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = HolidayCreateSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

```
class HolidayCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Holiday
        fields = ('id', 'country', 'city', 'holiday_date')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I have created a wrong model.
If I solve the above problem, I will have to make sure that no one creates a holiday on a non existing location (ie country-city combo).

I solved the above problem by correcting the model itself:
and changing

```
class Holiday(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='location', on_delete='CASCADE')
    holiday_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```